# Errors trying to Linq join and pass back a ViewModel C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting a few errors back trying to do a join in Linq for two database tables. In my database I have a table for Participant and one for Gender.
I have 3 models in use - Participant, Gender and ParticipantDetailsViewModel. (Eventually I want to switch out other participant details to allow more data abstraction e.g. a table of cities).

**Participant**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCManageParticipants.Models
{
    public class Participant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Gender**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCManageParticipants.Models
{
    public class Gender
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ParticipantDetailsViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCManageParticipants.Models
{
    public class ParticipantDetailsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller I have the following method to handle the Details page:

```
public ActionResult Details([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int participantId = 0)
        {
            // Check participant exists
            Participant participant = _db.Participants.Find(participantId);

            if (participant == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var model = (from p in _db.Participants
                        join g in _db.Genders on p.Gender equals g.Id
                        where p.Id == participantId
                        select new ParticipantDetailsViewModel
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            SiteId = p.SiteId,
                            Status = p.Status,
                            Gender = g.Name,
                            Title = p.Title,
                            Name = p.Name,
                            City = p.City,
                            Postcode = p.Postcode,
                            Telephone = p.Telephone,
                            Notes = p.Notes
                        });

            return View(model);
        }
```

When I debug the app I get to returning the model from the controller and have the following in the results view:
[image: model results view]

For testing I've stripped down my details view so that I have the following:

```
@model MVCManageParticipants.Models.ParticipantDetailsViewModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Details"; }

<h2>Details2</h2>
@Model.Id
@Model.Gender
```

And I receive the following error:

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MVCManageParticipants.Models.ParticipantDetailsViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCManageParticipants.Models.ParticipantDetailsViewModel'.*

At a loss as to what the issue is and how to fix it.

Comment: `model` in your case is a LINQ query which can result in more than one entities while your view expects only one object as Model. try `return View(model.FirstOrDefault);`.

Comment: Just a small note. I keep seeing people doing joins manually when EF was specifically designed to help you do them automatically; you can just have `public Gender Gender {get;set;}` on your `Participant` and if the context is configured correctly you can just access that and EF will do the join for you under the covers. So in the projection you could just have `Gender = p.Gender.Name` and forget all about the join.

Comment: @AlexPaven can you provide any resources explaining this further please? It's still working using this method but the gender field is empty.

Comment: @AlexPaven  new column in the table was created called Gender_ID that needed to be populated.

Thanks for the tip, that's easier and cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your Action should be:

```
public ActionResult Details([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int participantId = 0)
{
    // Check participant exists
    Participant participant = _db.Participants.Find(participantId);

    if (participant == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var model = (from p in _db.Participants
                    join g in _db.Genders on p.Gender equals g.Id
                    where p.Id == participantId
                    select new ParticipantDetailsViewModel
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        SiteId = p.SiteId,
                        Status = p.Status,
                        Gender = g.Name,
                        Title = p.Title,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        City = p.City,
                        Postcode = p.Postcode,
                        Telephone = p.Telephone,
                        Notes = p.Notes
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(model);
}
```

The result of `Where` clause is a Collection and not a Single object. The result might be a Collection with one Object but that would still be a Collection whereas the View expects a Single `ParticipantDetailsViewModel` object and not a Collection of it. The `FirstOrDefault` would just get the First object from the Result of preceding Query (which is what your View needs)

Comment: Looks promising, however now I'm getting this error: The entity or complex type 'MVCManageParticipants.Models.ParticipantDetailsViewModel' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: ParticipantDetailsViewModel is not part of DbContext, right? I mean it is not an Entity?

Comment: That's it. Looks like it added
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVCManageParticipants.Models.ParticipantDetailsViewModel> ParticipantDetailsViewModels { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you try to pass IQueryble to your view, please try to call "FirstOrDefault" in controller or change your model to List and call "ToList" in controller.

Answer (score 1):

it you have return model is List .

So you have receive The error .

your always correct Answer but small change Your query.

You have Used FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault

```
var model = (from p in _db.Participants
                    join g in _db.Genders on p.Gender equals g.Id
                    where p.Id == participantId
                    select new ParticipantDetailsViewModel
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        SiteId = p.SiteId,
                        Status = p.Status,
                        Gender = g.Name,
                        Title = p.Title,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        City = p.City,
                        Postcode = p.Postcode,
                        Telephone = p.Telephone,
                        Notes = p.Notes
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```